# Find elements which exists in the most of the lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Input:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,5,7],[1,9,3],[4,3,8]]
```

Expected result:

```
[1,3]
```

(add element to result if it exists in over 50% of input lists).

I'm looking for elegant, pythonic solution :). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the unelegant/unpythonic solution you already came up with so we can help you improve it?

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that each element will appear at most once per subgroup?  I.e. will this ever appear in the input:  `[[1, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`?

Comment: 1) I didn't write any solution so far. 
2) Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = [[1,2,3],[1,5,7],[1,9,3],[4,3,8]]
>>> count = Counter(term for subseq in s for term in set(subseq))
>>> [k for k,v in count.items() if v > len(s)//2]
[1, 3]
```

[Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is a handy tool which, well, counts things:

```
>>> Counter([1,2,3,3,2])
Counter({2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1})
```

[.. oops, just noticed you're using Python 3, so we need .items()].

Comment: Thank you! It looks (and works) great. I only had to change "iteritems" to "items", probably because of python3.